# ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, django

when i try to run this code

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Test', 'This is a test', 'your@email.com', ['toemail@email.com'],
 fail_silently=False)
```

in shell i am getting the import error:Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE is undefined

I fixed this(C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin) path in environment variable...but still the problem was not fixed...Please say anyone how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the command, python manage.py shell?

Comment: yaeh..this is my project path(D:\kalai\python project\django-classifieds-master\extras\project), in that i run the command "python manage.py shell"... after that only i run the above mail code in shell..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should run manage.py,in manage.py,it set DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE using os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

Comment: where you run your code? you run python manage.py shell and continue to type your code in console or other method ? DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE is set in manage.py,i donot understand how you set DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE in your settings.py,since Django need DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE to find settting.py

Comment: Actually i have one project..in that i am using send_mail() function in my views...after running the command "python manage.py runserver" in command prompt in that i didnt get any error,but in my browser i am getting SMTP connection error, so for that i test the send_mail() in shell within my project path(D:\kalai\python project\django-classifieds-master\extras\project), while running that function here i am getting that import error.....

Comment: I run the test code following your steps:
1). run python manage.py shell
2). run your code
from django.core.mail import send_mail
  send_mail('Test', 'This is a test', 'your@email.com',    ['toemail@email.com'],
 fail_silently=False)
3).it threw exception related to smtp

It didn't throw "import error ..." exception in my environment.The connection parameter is set None in send_mail and i didn't configure my pc as smtp server,so it threw the exception related to smtp and failed to send email,i think this is reasonable.Anything different between us?

Comment: i cleared my import error by setting the PYTHONPATH and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE varible in environment variable, now i am getting SMTP authentication error...i configured my settings.py with SMTP, but still i am getting SMTP authentication error..how to fix this???

Comment: Some related fields in settings.py are set correctly ?for example EMAIL_HOST,EMAIL_PORT,EMAIL_HOST_USER,EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD.Detailed explanation you can refer:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

Comment: i set the code like this:

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.SMTP.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'testmail123sample@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

but still the SMTP problem is not fixed

Comment: i amnot a gmail user.i think you need to check your Gmail SMTP setting,the below link may be helpful for you：https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: thank you...after i changed my gmail settings my SMTP error is solved... i changed my settings by this link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps i.e here i enable the option less secure apps then the error is solved to me....